# ssl certificate - identity not verified with godaddy

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I followed all the steps to create a unique certificate that looks like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExADALBgkqhkiG9w0BBwGggDCCAmowggHXAhAF
UbM77e50M63v1Z2A/5O5MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEOBAUAMF8xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMSAw
(.......)
E+cFEpf0WForA+eRP6XraWw8rTN8102zGrcJgg4P6XVS4l39+l5aCEGGbauLP5W6
K99c42ku3QrlX2+KeDi+xBG2cEIsdSiXeQS/16S36ITclu4AADEAAAAAAAAA
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Here are the steps I have taken:**

1. went to my WHM account > SSL/TLS and generated an SSL certificate and signing request
2. clicked on 'install an ssl certificate on a domain' > click 'browse certificate' > selected 'gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt' and it filled in everything for me, then clicked 'install'

I used godaddy as the provider

I can go on my website through https:// but it tells me it's untrusted. I've been breaking my head trying to figure out why.

I then found this http://www.symphonious.net/2008/06/04/tomcat-os-x-safari-and-godaddy-ssl-certificates/ and I wasn't clear on how to do certain steps.

It recommends using ca_bundle.crt but when I tried coping the code into 'certificate authority bundle' it will say it's incorrect.

This
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5238/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-apache
is not helpful as I don't know where to find the place indicated instep 1 or where the httpd.conf or ssl.conf file is located.

Comment: Please update the ticket with the specific domain as there are many test tools that can quickly spot the issue.

Comment: Check your site against https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/. It will probably tell you what went wrong. Just a guess: missing intermediate certificates or wrong order.

Comment: I got this when checking my url "The certificate is self-signed. Users will receive a warning when accessing this site unless the certificate is manually added as a trusted certificate to their web browser. You can fix this error by buying a trusted SSL certificate" how do I get it signed by the provider?

Comment: Did you skip the step where you should give the csr file to GoDaddy and they give you back a signed SSL certificate? I don't see that listed in your question. You would have had to pay GoDaddy for this so it's not something you could do without knowing or the WHM control panel could have done for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about Apache config, but with Windows IIS after you import a SSL cert you have to go into the IIS manager and set the Web site to then use that Cert on a specific port. I'm assuming that Apache will be similar. Is your config similar to this: http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm

Comment: where do i find /etc/httpd ? i cannot see anything in etc folder

Comment: @user252296 Try this and tell me the output: dir /etc/httpd/*

Comment: it gives a giant list but at the bottom i see httpd.exp libphp5.so* mod_bwlimited.so* mod_disable_suexec.so* mod_suphp.so*

Comment: So you need to find ssl.conf so look for it by: dir /etc/httpd/vhosts.d/ssl.conf or dir /etc/httpd/sites/ssl.conf then use nano or vim to edit the file: sudo nano /etc/httpd/*/ssl.conf

Comment: /etc/httpd/sites/ssl.conf: No such file or directory
/etc/httpd/vhosts.d/ssl.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Also to your above comment about getting it signed by a provider, that is what you did by buying one from GoDaddy, now you need to tell Apache which SSL cert to serve when people connect to your site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15887/discussion-between-user252296-and-george).